# CSS Two classes using one property with multiple settings

Tags: html, css, class, properties, element

I want to set the common parts of a property with one class, and then the discrete portions with a second set of classes. In this case I want to have 1 class where I can adjust the border thickness that will apply to all the 1-n discrete city classes. With the following sample the border does not get applied at all. I have a constraint where I have to make it work in IE8 (*sigh*)

```
.cityImage {
  border: solid 5px;
}

.chicago {
  border: #333;
}
.detroit {
  border: #999;
}
(and the list continues for about 10 items)
_______________

<img class="cityImage chicago" src="http:... />
<img class="cityImage detroit" src="http:... />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was slighltly off

```
.cityImage {
  border: solid 5px;
}

.chicago {
  border: #333;
}
.detroit {
  border: #999;
}
```

should be

```
.cityImage {
  border: solid 5px;
}

.chicago {
  border-color: #333;
}
.detroit {
  border-color: #999;
}
```

**Note:** You do not need to state an intial border color but if you *don't* it will default to the current text color applicable to the element..stated or inherited.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is border-color: #999. This can then be added with the parent class cityImage.